# Onkeydown not working javascript

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

Here is my code

```
document.onkeydown = function (a) {
    if (a.which == 13) {
        alert("Not Anymore");

    }
}

document.onkeydown = function (b) {
    if (b.which == 65) {
        auto();
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function (c) {
    if (c.which == 83) {
        auto2();

    }
}
```

Only the last snippet works can someone explain why this is happening
check my website and you can see it isnt working when you press a but when you press b it is

Thanks, I appreciate the help and feedback

Comment: The event handlers are overriden by the last, so only the last works

Comment: [`document.addEventListener(`…`);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) would be another option.

Answer (score 5):

You're binding the same event on the `document` multiple times. So, the later event handlers override the previous event handlers just like the functions with same name does. You need to bind only one event handler and use `if... else` in it.

You can use this

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert("Not Anymore");
    } else if (e.which == 65) {
        auto();
    } else if (e.which == 83) {
        auto2();
    }
};
```

Also, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `onkeydown`.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (a) {
    if (a.which == 13) {}
    ...
}, false);
```

Comment: To expand on this, nowadays its a common best practice to use event listeners; document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){})

Comment: @DuncanMilrad You're welcome! If your problem is solved, kindly accept the answer